# trouble using count() and group by

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have table named Products, that looks like:

```
maker      model   type
---------- -------  -----
A          1232      PC
A          1233      PC
A          1276      Printer
A          1401      Printer
A          1408      Printer
A          1298      Laptop
A          1752      Laptop
B          1121      PC
B          1750      Laptop
C          1321      Laptop
D          1433      Printer
D          1288      Printer
E          1260      PC
E          1434      Printer
E          2112      PC
E          2113      PC
```

And I need to get the maker that produces more than 1 model but that models should be the same type... Here it should be `maker = D and Type = Printer`.

I spent the whole day using count(model)>1 and count(type)=1 etc. Nothing works.

Comment: Can you lay out a desired output?

Comment: I wrote it. It should be 'D' maker and 'Printer' type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT maker,
       MIN(type) AS type
FROM Products
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1
       AND COUNT(DISTINCT model) >1
```

Comment: God, I've dancing around distinct a lot times (facepalm) :DD Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can u explain what does MIN(type) do here?

Comment: I didn't want to group by it as i want to have an agragate function (count) on it. So if i still want to display it, then i have to add it there. I could use MAX()...

Comment: means that it chooses from two same values? Printer and Printer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine the `maker` that has more than one `model` of the same `type`, then you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the result:

```
select maker
from products
group by maker
having count(distinct model) > 1 -- more than one model
  and count(distinct type) = 1   -- same type
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34ce2/3)  If you want to return everything for each `maker`, then use can use

```
select p.maker, p.model, p.type
from products p
where maker in (select maker
                from products t
                group by maker
                having count(distinct model) > 1
                  and count(distinct type) = 1);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34ce2/6)

Comment: Thank u very much. The second is better. I would accept ur answer but Giannis Paraskevopoulos answered first.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct maker, type
from products t1
where exists (
    select 1 from products t2
    where t1.maker = t2.maker
    and t1.model <> t2.model
    and t1.type = t2.type
) and not exists (
    select 1 from products t2
    where t2.maker = t1.maker
    and t2.type <> t1.type
)
```

Comment: it doesn't returns the desired values... Please, look at the accepted answer.

Comment: @Daria, misunderstood your original question, it should work now although the accepted answer is probably better

Answer (score 1):

```
With TempTable
AS(
    SELECT
        Maker ,Count(DISTINCT type) Count1,Count(model) as mcount
    FROM
        Products 
    GROUP BY
        Maker
    HAVING Count(DISTINCT type)=1
)

Select a.Maker from TempTable a
Where a.mcount IN (Select MAX(mcount) from TempTable)
```

Comment: You should format your code in a proper way while answering.